# alguien que me pueda resolver esta duda por que razon me parece error 1052 y me dice que es ambiguo que es lo que tengo que hacer son subconsulta

Tags: mysql

```
select alumnos.id, alumnos.nombre, calificaciones.n_materia, 
calificaciones.parcial_1, calificaciones.parcial_2, 
calificaciones.parcial_3 
from alumnos INNER JOIN calificaciones 
where id = (select id 
            from calificaciones 
            where n_materia = 'h matematicas');
```

ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: select alumnos.id, alumnos.nombre, calificaciones.n_materia, calificaciones.parcial_1, calificaciones.parcial_2, calificaciones.parcial_3 from alumnos INNER JOIN calificaciones where id=(select id from calificaciones where id='100262'); esta es la que tengo duda

Comment: Al hacer el INNER JOIN seguramente tengas dos campos id, el de alumnos y el de calificaciones. En el where el motor de base de datos no sabe cual de los dos usar, de ahí el error. Pon calificaciones.id y probablemente se resuelva. Aparte la subconsulta parece algo inútil, con perdón, te va a devolver '100262'

Answer (score 1):

No veo mucho sentido a la subconsulta, el error se debe a que la columna id no sabe a que tabla pertenece. Entendiendo que en la tabla calificaciones se encuentra el id del alumno, puedes probar con una consulta como esta:

```
SELECT 
    alumnos.id, 
    alumnos.nombre, 
    calificaciones.n_materia, 
    calificaciones.parcial_1, 
    calificaciones.parcial_2, 
    calificaciones.parcial_3 
FROM 
    alumnos al JOIN calificaciones cal ON al.id = cal.id
    #cal.id es el id del alumno
WHERE
    cal.n_materia = 'h matematicas'
```

Otra cosa sería si no tuvieras relación entre la tabla alumnos y calificaciones, entonces deberías crear una tabla relacionando alumnos con materias, por ejemplo, alumno_tiene_materias con el id_alumno y con id_materia. Con esto y otro JOIN enlazarías con la tabla calificaciones.